# How to pass JVM arguments to a native JavaFX 2 application created with Inno Setup

Tags: java, maven, javafx-2, out-of-memory, inno-setup

I have a JavaFX 2 desktop application. I've used javafx-maven-plugin and Inno Setup to create a native bundle for Windows (.exe installer).

When I install the application on Windows Server 2008, I get an out of memory exception, because of the low heap size.

How can I pass JVM arguments to increase the heap size (-Xmx) in this scenario?

Is there any way to specefy jvm arguments to be called when creating the native bundle with Inno Setup?

Comment: Do you mean you get the error the the installer is launching your Java application at end of the installation (as specified by `[Run]` section).

Comment: How are you creating the `exe` file?

Comment: No, I get an out of memory error during the execution of my program. I'm creating the .exe file via javafx-maven-plugin. In maven I type "mvn jfx:native" and that creates the installer using Inno Setup.

Comment: Is there any way to specify Xmx parameter in Inno Setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do in via Inno Setup, because it just creates an installer for your application.

However, you can use the [`jvmArgs`](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/native-mojo.html#jvmArgs) for the goal [`javafx:native`](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/native-mojo.html). Add them in the configuration tag of the `javafx-maven-plugin` to set the Xmx, Xms or any other JVM arguments.

```
<configuration>
    <jvmArgs>
        <argument>-Xmx2g</argument>
        <argument>-Xms256m</argument>
    </jvmArgs>
</configuration>
```